# ZeroMQ, Does Scala Binding slow it down considerably

Tags: scala, zeromq

We are using a pull push mechanism similar to the perf tests specified here for ZeroMQ. http://www.zeromq.org/results:perf-howto

For the throughput test with a message size of 4.3KB and 100,000 messages i get a performance of 85K msg/sec

vikas@vikas-laptop:~/w/software/exploded/zeromq-2.1.10/perf$ local_thr tcp://127.0.0.1:5555 4300 100000
message size: 4300 [B]
message count: 100000
mean throughput: 85203 [msg/s]
mean throughput: 2930.983 [Mb/s]

However with the code in Scala and using the Scala binding 0.0.3 i get less than 15K msg/sec.

Gist here https://gist.github.com/1496406

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When testing 0MQ throughput, you need to take a little care to get meaningful figures.

First, use a machine with sufficient cores, or two machines on a fast network.

Second, send sufficient messages to actually stress the test case for a few seconds. 100K is too few, probably 1M would be better.

Third, test with different message sizes to see the impact of different operations. Use 1-byte messages to test the cost of the language API (Scala). Use 100 byte messages to test the cost of I/O. Use 1K messages to test the cost of memory copying. You will usually see a curve.

Comment: Thanks Pieter for your response, the gist that i posted is just one scenario but as you suggested we tried with various combinations of message sizes and number of messages. The numbers are nowhere near what we get with  perf tests. I made changes as suggested by Viktor, see the mail thread here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/scala-user/zeromq$20scala$20binding/scala-user/EKPxFTuWq7o/_UCcY9mh0zwJ still there is no improvement close to what we would expect.